# branch & bound error : Node1 cannot be cast to java.lang.Comparable

Tags: java, algorithm, comparator, comparable, branch-and-bound

I am trying to implement branch & bound search algorithm in java. I know its concept (how it works), but I am not sure how to implement it.

I found some examples on google but they are way more complex and I can't seem to understand them. I want to implement it in a simple way. Also most of them are not in java.

Following is the relevant method where my search starts (This is just a part of  my code).
I think my for loop needs to get modified appropriately to store the frontier nodes and costs and then get the node with least cost and then perform the search again until the goal node is found adding the cumulative costs.
So I guess recursive method works best for this. But I am not sure how to implement.

The following is not giving me any compiling error but is giving me run time error as `Node1 cannot be cast to java.lang.Comparable`. Does anyone be kindly look into  this issue? I have been trying to do it since hours but cant seem to find any solution.

ALSO, any small piece of code which directs me in a right path would be much helpful.

```
 public void Search(Node1[] nodes, String startNode, int size){

  List<String> frontierNodes = new ArrayList<String>();
  Queue<Node1> frontierCosts = new PriorityQueue<Node1>();

    for(int i=0; i<size;i++) {

        if(startNode.equals(nodes[i].getStartNode())) { // user enters the startNode and goalNode          

           frontierNodes.add(nodes[i].getEndNode());               
           frontierCosts.add(new Node1(nodes[i].getCost())); 
           frontierCosts.peek();
           System.out.println("Min cost" +frontierCosts.peek());
           int nodesLength = nodes.length - (frontierNodes.size()); 
           i--;
           System.out.println("remaining search nodes length" +nodesLength);

           //Search(nodes, frontierCosts.peek().getEndNode() ,nodesLength); // RECURSIVE CALL?
        } 
    }

}
```

Following is the Node1 class which stores the file information

```
class Node1 {
   String start, end;
   double cost;

   public Node1(String start, String end, double cost){
       this.start = start;
       this.end = end;
       this.cost = cost;
   }

   public Node1(double cost) { // alternate constructor to store cost in   priority queue
      this.cost = cost;
   }

   public String getStartNode(){
      return start;
   }

   public String getEndNode(){
      return end;
   }

   public double getCost(){
      return cost;
   }
}
```

Following is the file format(startNode endNode cost)

```
A B 10 
A C 12
B D 6
....
```

[EDIT]:

I want to implement branch and bound search, where the program asks the user to enter `startNode` and `goalNode` and then access the data from `Node1` class (where the data from file is stored) and then program enters the `search` method (above method) passing all the `nodes`, `startNode` and `length of nodes(size)`.
If the startNode matches any of the node1[].getStartNode, then it stores the corresponding expanded nodes in `frontierNodes` and their corresponding costs in `frontierCosts` in a priority queue (to pick the least cost). 
Then the program peeks() the priority queue & selects the least cost node (front of queue) and then searches again (recursive call to above search method?) with that particular node as startNode and the search continues.
When the program reaches the new nodes, the cost at each new node should get the cumulative cost of the path visited so far and the program should output the path and the cost.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PriorityQueue needs the data structure that implements Comparable interface unless you pass in a Comparator as a [constructor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.html#PriorityQueue(int,%20java.util.Comparator)).

The change should be pretty straightforward.

```
class Node1 implements Comparable<Node1> {
    String start, end;
    double cost;

    public Node1(String start, String end, double cost){
        this.start = start;
        this.end = end;
        this.cost = cost;
    }

    public Node1(double cost) { // alternate constructor to store cost in   priority queue
        this.cost = cost;
    }

    public String getStartNode(){
        return start;
    }

    public String getEndNode(){
        return end;
    }

    public double getCost(){
        return cost;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Node1 o) {
        return Double.compare(this.cost, o.cost);
    }
}
```

Note that if you want the result to be deterministic and the cost is not unique, you might need to use start/end node as part of the comparison as well.

For your main logic, there are a couple things not quite right.

1. Your function arguments should include what goal node it is.
2. Your function arguments should include how much cost you have used so far so that you can keep track of that if you want to use a recursive function.
3. Your function should return the minimum cost to reach to the node.
4. If your graph can have a loop, consider a mechanism to ensure that it will not revisit the nodes it has visited previously.
5. Once you have a possible solution with an acceptable cost, you need to use that cost as an upper bound to ensure that you will not continue to visit more nodes if the cost has gone higher than the best solution so far.

Comment: Thank you for this, but when I am implementing this, the program is getting stuck in infinite loops? I dont understand why

Comment: The code is wrong since it only adds stuff into the priority queue but never takes anything out. If you describe more exactly what your code is supposed to do, I might be able to help.

Comment: Oh sorry! I will edit the question and explain there .Please have a look.

Comment: Yes those are the points exactly what expected. With point 4. the nodes in file (graph) doesn't have a loop and so I think I don't need to implement anything separately to track that.

Comment: I am not sure how to return the minimum cost, I mean how to add the cumulative cost for each and every expanded node and return the cost. Could you kindly be able to help me with this?

Comment: It sounds like a homework assignment so I don't think I can help much further than this. If you pass in the cost so far as an argument, you should be able to keep track of the cumulative cost. The minimum cost at each step would be the min cost from visiting each neighbor nodes.

Comment: Okay thanks so much for the clues, I will try to implement them now :) I just have one last general question, if I do recursive call to `search` method, will each and every recursive call creates new empty `frontierNodes`  arraylist and new  `frontierCosts` queue according to my search method above (because they are inside the method)? or will it work fine?

Comment: @Dee, yes, you should reconstruct `frontierCost` but you don't really need `frontierNodes` though. And if you want to follow the logic you plan to have, you might need more than one loop. The first loop would be to add the neighbors to the queue while another loop is to try out each neighbor.